# Selenium web driver to automate Oracle ADF login

Tags: selenium

This is my first post in stack overflow so please forgive me if I haven't included any important details.

I am currently trying to write a java code using selenium web driver to automate Oracle ADF login and then performing various tests but failing with the following error

Currently I have the following code. Not trying to do anything fancy here but just trying to send the username but it's failing. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    public static void main (final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


System.out.println("*******************");
System.out.println("Launching FF browser");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("http://fusion11.com.au:19000/workspace/index.jsp");
String ActualTitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(ActualTitle);
String ExpectedTitle = "Oracle Enterprise Performance Management System Workspace, Fusion Edition";
Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedTitle, ActualTitle);
    
Boolean verifyTitle = ActualTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Oracle Enterprise Performance Management System Workspace, Fusion Edition");
System.out.println(verifyTitle);
WebElement GetUserName= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bpm.Logon.1.txtUser\"]"));
GetUserName.sendKeys("username");
System.out.println(GetUserName);
```

}

Failing with the following error
[Selenium - Unable to Locate Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6hTC.png)

Answer (score 0):

for the locator //*[@id="bpm.Logon.1.txtUser"]

Remove the \ before bpm and remove the \ after txtuser

example --

Thread.sleep(5000);// this is incase your implicit wait does not work

> Blockquote

WebElement GetUserName= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="bpm.Logon.1.txtUser"]"));

Comment: It doesn't work.

Eclipse throws it as syntax error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 bpm cannot be resolved
 Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 Syntax error on token "txtUser", ( expected after this token
 Syntax error on token ")", delete this token